# Is it possible to determine which modal / component I will show when I click on a component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-components

I'm working on small Angular 5 project, and I have a simple component which is representing an food product and it looks like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This component is nested component, it is part of my main component.

When I click on this component, quantity component/modal is shown:

```
<app-product-item (onInfoEdit)="InfoModal.show($event)"></app-product-item>
```

But now I would like to show another modal if some condition is satisfied, for example

If condition is satisfied then show this quantity modal (which is component itself) otherwise show some another modal (which is another component), so:

```
 <app-product-item "if something is satisfied than this code on the right is ok otherwise lets display another modal with different method" (onInfoEdit)="InfoModal.show($event) (onSomethingElse)="AnotherModal.show($event)></app-product-item>
```

So I'm not sure if this is even possible because I need to show 2 different modals ( different components ) on same component's click, so basically if product has some property defined than show quantity info, otherwise show product info, and quantity info and product info are separated components..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Write one method & call it on (onInfoEdit) or on (click) :  `(onInfoEdit)="showModals($event)"` In that method, check different conditions & then show desired modals.

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking at something like this:

```
<app-product-item #productItem 
                  (click)="productItem?.product?.property ? InfoModal.show($event) : AnotherModal.show($event)"
                  (onInfoEdit)="InfoModal.show($event)"
                  (onSomethingElse)="AnotherModal.show($event)">
</app-product-item>
```

where "property" would be a property of "product", which would be an object defined inside your Product Item Component.

Please also note that the conditional statements inside templates are not recommended and should be carried to the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating component which will conditionally render one of two components. One condition will load `info` component and other condition will load `quantity` component. Let's call this conditional modal something like: `food-modal`, inside `food-modal.component.html` template the code could look like:

```
<h1>CONDITIONAL MODAL CONTAINER</h1>
<ng-container *ngIf="product.name === 'Chicken'">
    <app-info [product]="product"></app-info>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="product.name === 'Cow'">
    <app-quantity [product]="product"></app-quantity>
</ng-container>
```

And inside `food-modal.component.ts` the code could look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/Product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-food-modal',
  templateUrl: './food-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./food-modal.component.css']
})
export class FoodModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public product: Product;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

All you have to do now is call this component where you want it and pass in `Product` model. For sake of demonstration I'll put everything inside `app` component in order to load `food-modal`. The `app.component.html` could look like:

```
 <app-food-modal [product]="chickenProduct">
 </app-food-modal>
```

And inside `app.component.ts` code could be like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './models/Product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public chickenProduct: Product;

  constructor() {
    this.chickenProduct = {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 2,
        name: 'Chicken'
    };
  }
}
```

Now `app` component will pass `Product` object named *chickenProduct* to `food-modal` component and bind it to modal's `product` property. After that the conditional rendering will happen.

Rest of the code could look like:

**info.component.html**:

```
<p>
 This modal is for INFO. Product name is: {{ product.name }}
</p>
```

**info.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/Product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info.component.css']
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public product: Product;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**quantity.component.html**:

```
<p>
 This modal is for QUANTITY. Product name is: {{ product.name }}
</p>
```

**quantity.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/Product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quantity',
  templateUrl: './quantity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quantity.component.css']
})
export class QuantityComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public product: Product;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**product.model.ts**:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  quantity: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I've implemented solution like this and everything worked fine! Change `name` property of product to *Cow* and conditional fire will happen and load `quantity` component, take it back to *Chicken* and conditional fire will load `info` component.

I assume you just wanted to know how to trigger conditional firing, so that's why I've done this by hard coding string, checking whether name of product is `Chicken` or `Cow`.